# Mathematical exploration on chaos theory, trigonometry or probability

Tags: trigonometry

I am actually in need to do a mathematical exploration for my International Baccalaureate program. There's no specific topic but I've chosen to explore chaos theory since I found it to be very interesting. However, I don't know what mathematical aspect can be calculated or investigated from this very topic. It would be really helpful if you can suggest one, even if it's out of chaos theory. Other topics that I would want to do are trigonometry and probability.

Answer (score 0):

Those three things are dramatically different, and I'd suggest picking one more in line with what you're learning in your IB program.  I'd choose either trig or probability.  If you choose trig, you can look into interesting things like ancient Greek perspectives on it, including the sophistication of it as a field of study even thousands of years ago.

If that doesn't entertain you, a more modern treatment of probability that is accessible to IB students would be to compare and contrast the various schools of thought of probability and the philosophy of them.  For example, is probability defined only in terms of how frequently events occur, or is there an underlying framework that describes "probabilistic variables" more fundamentally?  What are the different methods of representing, working with, and using probability?   How can probabilistic models be applied to the real world?  How do you know if your model is correct, if it relies on probabilistic variables that you can only measure once or twice?  What is a good measurement, and why? (And...the list goes on).

With chaos theory you typically have to know a bit about dynamic systems, which isn't exactly inaccessible to you but I'd stick to the above two topics instead, as the mathematics required for a reasonable treatment of them would be well within most HS IB programs.

Comment: That's more like a history behind it. I actually need to do something related to the maths behind something. Eg: the mathematical model of rainfall. But that's a project that's been done. I'm planning on relating music and trigonometry but I have no clear idea on how to relate them. Thanks for the suggestion btw

Comment: If you'd like to relate music and trig, look into "Fourier analysis".  It's a BIT above high school level, but it isn't overly complex to use it.  It allows you to represent any signal (not just music, but music will do) in terms of sinusoids (sine/cosine functions)

Comment: Heartbeat also can?

Comment: yes, sort of.  It depends on how you mean.  A signal that is taken from a heart that is beating at a constant rate will be decomposed into an obvious to interpret Fourier series - you'll get a dominant frequency indicating heart rate, and a bunch of other stuff indicating shape of the pulse.  However, if the heart beat's frequency changes as you are taking the data, it won't be nearly so simple. You'll have to do more advanced techniques.  That being said, just take heart beat data with constant pulse for like 10 seconds and analyze it

Comment: Actually I need to do a whole paperwork on this. This might be interesting. But what do you think I should put as my focus? Because I don't think just analysing 10sec of the heart beat would be enough to do a paper work on. What do you think?

Comment: I definitely think it will if you set it up right.  It's not just "take 10s of data once and never again".  It's "develop a method to analyze 10s worth of data, then take multiple data sets and demonstrate that your method is valid, so that anyone else who uses it with some other set of 10s worth of data will be able to extract the same information you did"